# Is it more secure to stay on Yosemite, or use Sierra with SIP disabled?

Tags: macos, security

As we all probably know, El Capitan introduced SIP. While it's an excellent security measure, it's also disabled many handy tools and utilities that I've come to rely on - for example, [Asepsis](http://asepsis.binaryage.com/) and a few utilities on Wine.

Until now, I've been staying on Yosemite for the sake of still being able to use these tools under native support. However, now that Sierra is out and I'm two major OS versions behind, I'd like to weigh the pros and cons of an upgrade. Namely, will disabling SIP on Sierra put me in a less secure position than staying on Yosemite, or will I be assuming the same security risks either way?

The [arguments](http://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/) against [disabling SIP](http://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away) are [well-documented](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11), so I'd like to avoid answers like "SIP is more important than having your tools". Assuming my tools are top priority, what's the most secure environment for me to use them in?

Comment: Yosemite does not support SEP, versions after El Captain, do support it.  So if your currently using Yosemite, which does not have SEP, your security posture will be exactly the same with regards to SEP if its disabled and your running El Captain or Sierra.  The benefit of upgrading is you get all security updates released.  I say that, but also must sadly, issue a close vote because this question seems extremly broad.  The only way I know how to answer it, would be to list all the security changes besides SEP, that came with those two updates.  Which would be an extremely long list.

Comment: @Ramhound that makes sense to me - I didn't know if there were older security measures removed / replaced by SIP that would put me in a worse position by disabling it. I understand on the close vote - can you suggest any way I can make the question less broad?

Comment: Your question is like asking, what security do I lose, if I use a version of Windows which doesn't the improved versions of DEP.  The advantages of a specific security feature should be weighed against the disadvantages.  I see no way of answering this question, without generating a list like that, which honestly would be based on my opionion on the matter.  If I needed to use Wine, I would upgrade to Sierra, then run a VM running an older version of OS X for that purpose.  If running a VM didn't acomplish my goals, I would disable the conflicting feature, but enable what I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sticking with an older version of the OS obviously means you don't get the various *other* security improvements in the most recent versions (better SSL/TLS crypto, Sierra's improvements to how Gatekeeper handles disk images, etc).
- Apple usually seems to release security patches for only the most recent 2 or 3 versions of the OS. Since Sierra's release, Yosemite *might* continue to receive patches. For a while. Maybe.
- On the other hand, upgrading and turning off SIP means you lose the kext signing requirements that Yosemite had. These got rolled into SIP in El Capitan, and so when you turn SIP off, these go away as well.
- On the gripping hand, it's possible to *partially* disable SIP, turning off only the parts that interfere with your tools, while leaving other parts (e.g. kext signing) enabled. For example, if you need DTrace to work but the other SIP restrictions are ok, you could start in recovery mode and run the command `csrutil enable --without dtrace`.

  You may have to experiment to see which parts of SIP need to be turned off for your tools to work. The options are `--without kext`, `--without fs`, `--without debug`, `--without dtrace`, `--without nvram`, and `--no-internal`. You can check the current status with `csrutil status` (although this seems to show the running status, not the configured settings, meaning it doesn't update until you reboot). You can also clear the config back to default with `csrutil clear`.

  So that would be my recommendation: update, then do a surgical disable of just the parts of SIP that interfere with your tools.

  BTW, this partial disable feature isn't very well documented, but I found discussions of it [on apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11/209530#209530), as well as [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17452), [here](http://internals.exposed/blog/dtrace-vs-sip.html), and [here](https://www.idelta.info/archives/standalone-os-x-10-9-recovery-hd-backup/).

Comment: This is fantastic! I hadn't even considered it was possible to partially disable it. Thanks for the insight, I'll go with this!